# What tool to tighten nut on kitchen faucet?

Tags: tools, kitchen-sink

I'm not sure what the name of this nut is, but it has come loose.  I have a "basin wrench ratchet head" that goes on my socket set ratchet with a long arm but it can't get purchase because it is too bulky.  I have had some success with my thin vise grips but it eventually comes loose again and the nut is starting to get scratched up from it all.

What is the correct tool for this job?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these answers were great but not perfect for my circumstances. Today I had to replace the cartridge in my faucet, and in the process had to loosen this nut and tighten it once the work was done. Here is what I used -- as an answer to my question:

I used vice grips with their nose clamped onto the nut perpendicular -- so pointing straight up around the nut.

1. I had a helper use a non-marring strap wrench to hold the faucet
   straight at the top.
2. I tightened the nut from below using the vice grips.
3. Once hand tightened, I put a 12" socket extension between the vice
   grip jaws and turned a 1/4 turn to do the final tighten.

Maybe this answer is helpful to someone else in the future.

Comment: Well done and thanks for coming back to answer your question!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get plenty of leverage on it with either a channel-lock pliers or an adjustable (Crescent) wrench. Both give you parallel jaws, which are key to keeping them on the nut.

Comment: The issue @Steven has is the *'bulk'* of the tool. An adjustable wrench might fit, though it is more likely to slip than a fixed wrench, but it is doubtful channel-lock pliers would fit, and the angle of the jaws would make it unusable.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Exactly - I have tried both these tools and I can't get enough of a turn to make progress with these tools.

Answer (score 3):

As you state, a basin wrench is the correct tool. If the ratchet head basin wrench is too large, then a [dedicated self-adjusting wrench](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-use-a-basin-wrench-2718720) might fit. For spaces that are tighter yet, a [fixed-size basin wrench](https://www.lowcostplumbingsupplies.co.uk/catalog/product/view/id/9402) might fit better.

Since you'll not likely need to use the tool often, you might try an open-end wrench held *along* the supply lines, if you have one on hand of the correct size. It won't allow much torque before slipping, but it might suffice.

Comment: I will try to find a different basin wrench. I had not though about an open end wrench. I don't have one that wide, but it is a reasonable solution. I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: Both links in this answer go to the same page, Perhaps you meant a different destination for the fixed-size link?

Comment: @DougDeden, Thanks for catching my error! Second URL changed.